# Iterating through all Textareas with Javascript (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, textarea, iteration

I would like to perform something with all my text areas, however selecting all of them with `$("textarea")` wont do. Here's what I am trying to do in **Pseudo code**:

```
for each textarea do
  alert(textarea.val)
```

In my case, I need to do a Word replacement in all of my textareas, so I thought doing it with iteration would be a lot cleaner, however I cant figure out how to do it.

Here is what I currently do, which is very tedious:

```
var txtcode = $("#txt_banner1").text().replace("AFFURL",producturl);
$("#txt_banner1").text(txtcode);

var txtcode = $("#txt_banner2").text().replace("AFFURL",producturl);
$("#txt_banner2").text(txtcode);
```

... and on and on....

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("textarea").each(function(){
        this.value = this.value.replace("AFFURL",producturl);
    });
});
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VPDQt/)

Comment: +1 for REGULAR FREAKING JAVASCRIPT for getting the textarea's value instead of $(this).val() or .text() nonsense.

Comment: Accepted this one because of the regular javascript, which makes for better readability. Thanks! :)

Comment: I get ReferenceError: textarea is not defined when I try to do $("textarea") from within my code. I am executing this from within my $(document).ready function, is this not correct?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `.each` to iterate over all of the `textarea` elements and do what you need to with them via jQuery.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CteCp/)**

```
$('textarea').each(
    function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    }
);
```

**[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)**

Answer (score 3):

instead using id
do below

```
$("textarea").each ( function () {

// whatever u want
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/PKenB/

```
//alternative 1
$(function() {
    $('textarea').each(function() {
        alert($(this).text())
    })
})

//alternative 2 only those who has specific class  
$(function() {
    $('textarea.myTextArea').each(function() {
        alert($(this).text())
    })
})

//alternative 3, handpicked textareas    
$(function() {
    var handPicked = ['#2', '.myTextArea']
    for (x = 0; x < handPicked.length; x++) {
        alert($(handPicked[x]).text())
    }
})
```